# Group by expression not grouping data oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem with group data I have is a  group with a standard problem group by year and month. By when I try execude the code I have a wrong data

This is my existing query  :

```
select distinct to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM') datka, 
                sum((round(sum(pz.ILOSC_RUCH)* zamow.cena_nabycia_pln,1))) "wartość"

FROM OLAP_DANE.TSAP_STAN_RUCH_DWS pz,
     OLAP_DANE.MV_SAP_ZAMOW zamow
where zamow.NR_ZAMOW=pz.EBELN
  and to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM-DD')>='2019-10-01'
  and pz.material= zamow.material
  and zamow.WALUTA in ('PLN','EUR')

group by to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM'),
         pz.material,pz.ILOSC_RUCH, 
         zamow.cena_nabycia_pln
```

Data I would like to receive is :

```
Data     Count
2019-10  1000
2019-11  1000
2019-12  500
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. I'd try `group by  to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM')`.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, the GROUP BY returns no duplicate rows.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Also read [mcve].

Comment: Now I have a sum with no distinct month. I won't recive distinct months from this :

`2019-10 870,9
2019-10 766,9
2019-10 296,7
2019-10 1680
2019-10 1027,4
2019-10 8288,9
2019-10 2684,1
2019-10 952,4
2019-10 113,5
2019-10 706,8
2019-11 266,1
2019-10 618,6
2019-10 30,4
2019-10 7075,6
2019-10 31,4
2019-10 18,3
2019-11 21287,8`

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead!

Answer (score 0):

A SUM of a SUM won't do.

But only one SUM is needed if the GROUP BY only contains what's needed.

```
SELECT 
 to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM') datka, 
 round(SUM(pz.ILOSC_RUCH * zamow.cena_nabycia_pln),1) AS "wartość"
...
GROUP BY to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM')
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to group by just the field for the "month" -->to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM')

```
select to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM') datka
      ,sum((round(sum(pz.ILOSC_RUCH)* zamow.cena_nabycia_pln,1))) "wartość"
     --pz.material,
     --pz.ILOSC_RUCH, 
     --zamow.WALUTA, 
     --zamow.cena_nabycia_pln, 
FROM OLAP_DANE.TSAP_STAN_RUCH_DWS pz,
     OLAP_DANE.MV_SAP_ZAMOW zamow
where zamow.NR_ZAMOW=pz.EBELN
  and to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM-DD')>='2019-10-01'
  and pz.material= zamow.material
  and zamow.WALUTA in ('PLN','EUR')
--and pz.material='1115050016BS'
--and zamow.NR_ZAMOW='4100106405'
group by to_char(pz.data,'RRRR-MM')
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the nested `SUM` in your query is valid.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sum is ok it a sum of value

Answer (score -1):

Now I have a sum with no distinct month. I won't recive distinct months from this :

```
2019-10 870,9
2019-10 766,9
2019-10 296,7
2019-10 1680
2019-10 1027,4
2019-10 8288,9
2019-10 2684,1
2019-10 952,4
2019-10 113,5
2019-10 706,8
2019-11 266,1
2019-10 618,6
2019-10 30,4
2019-10 7075,6
2019-10 31,4
2019-10 18,3
2019-11 21287,8
```

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment so kindly put this in comment